# How to encrypt four digit code(only number), time limit 3 hours and not use database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I am making sms plugin and i have to send sms on mobile number in customer registration page.

My code digit length is **4 digit** and time limit is **3hr**. and sended code i am **not able to store in any database table**.

And i was send sms like random four digit okay? but when customer enter this code in system so how to check this code is valid or not can you give me suggestion.

Regards,
Jatin

Comment: 3 hour from the time of generation, or a 3 hour window like 12-15 (meaning that if you generate the code at 14:45, it has a lifespan of 15 minutes)?

Comment: You need one time password. Right! just go through the link and modify this as per your requirement. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/592275/OTP-One-Time-Password-Demystified

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you getting something missing see if we only get time and send to user but some user use this code after some days at that time so this code is working after few days same time.

Comment: No, my question was whether it has to be valid from the time of code generation, or whether it can be alive for a fixed window of time unrelated to code generation. Like, if you created the code right now, which at my location is 09:48 morning on the 11th of September. Does this code have to be valid to 12:48 today, or could it be valid from 08:00 today to 11:00 today? What are your requirements? I did not mean 12-15 on any day

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks for your response... i am explain you my requirements.... when customer register then i am sending one code for authentication on customer mobile and this code only four digit of any number and time limit 3 hour of that day only(not able to use database table) okay..then customer enter this code in system okay? and i want to verify this code again in my system.. for ex mr. x register in my system on 10:00 AM 11th of September 2014 and get one code in mobile and this code valid on 10:00 AM 11th of September 2014.. and if any question pls feel free to ask...

Comment: and how to encrypt current date-time(add three hours) in four digit and how to decrypt four digit to current date-time.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen sorry some mistack  in my above commnets....for example mr. x register in my system on 10:00 AM 11th of September 2014 and get one code in mobile and this code valid on 01:00 PM 11th of September 2014.

Comment: There is no way to get a code that is valid 3 hours from creation time unless you store it. Or you can say that all codes has to be created as though the seconds portion of the current time is always 0, and then just try all combinations the last 3 hours to see if any of those times would create the same code. WHY can't you store it somewhere?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that in order to validate a generated code, you need to be able to repeat the generation of it, and unless you know the time when it was created, you're left with just trying all possible times when the code could've been generated to see if any of the possible codes is the one being verified. If you allow timestamps down to seconds or milliseconds you're going to have *a lot* of possible codes that you need to create. Since you're limited to 4 digits, you can't encode the date and time into the code in a meaningful way.

Comment: okay.. thanks for replay.. reason for why we are not able to use database because we have multiple customer register at same time and when we store code with date and time in date base then my system performance very down so we are not able to use database.

Comment: This reminds me of Red lines with green ink comedy sketch - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg

Comment: why not fine tune your database then? what database engine are you using? maybe you should use a different database system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way is that in the code, you store the day and the hour and scramble the digits with a reversal algorithm, or you could have a table in your database where you could store a scrambled version of your random code with a creation date, or you can put the code in a cache that expires after three hours... There are a lot of choices...

Comment: can you give me any example or sample code so we can understand easly.and we are not able to create table in database so give me other solution pls.